# about the vector.push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a program as follows:

```
if(i = 0)
{   vector<int> data;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    data.push_back(2);
    data.push_back(3);
    sort(data.begin(),data.end());
    it = data.begin();
}

if(i = 0)
{   vector<int> data;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    data.push_back(5);
    data.push_back(1);
    sort(data.begin(),data.end());
    it = data.begin();
}
```

If I use the `vector<int>` two times, will it release automatically? Should I release the memory?

Comment: You are not using the vector 2 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory allocation for local variables is deleted automatically when the variable goes out of scope.

```
if(i == 0)
{
    std::vector<int> data; //local variable
}
//allocation for 'data' is deleted automatically
if(i == 0)
{
    std::vector<int> data; //this is not the same vector as above
    //in fact, the vector above no longer exists at this point
}
//allocation for 'data' is deleted automatically
```